# jQuery: how do I get all files from a directory on the web server

Tags: jquery, webserver

With just jQuery (I have no php), the code

```
var url = "/repository/load/t3.case";
$.get(url, function (data, status, xhr) {        
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

gets me a file from the webserver. But I would like a list of ALL files in the directory "/repository/load". I read that something like:

```
var fileextension = ".case";
var dir = "/repository/load";
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {

        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
            alert(dir + filename);
        });
    }
});
```

could give me that. But this just gives me a 404-not found. I added a ".htaccess" file to the folder (with "Options +Indexes") to make it browsable. This does not help.

How do I get all files (and directories) from a directory on the web server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of files on the web server, the web server would have to support a specific URL/query that would provide that list of files.  The client cannot list files on its own using Ajax.  Instead, it must make an Ajax call to the server requesting a list of files and the server must then implement a specific route/query to support that.  The server can then collect the list of files and return it as the response to that request.

HTTP does not have a built in file listing capability that would just be automatically supported.

Comment: thx, what does that specific route/query on the server look like?

Comment: @RoodVleven - it depends entirely on what language and framework you are using on your server.  You create the route yourself and you can make it anything and then you register a handler for that route using whatever web server framework you're using.  That handler, then does the directory listing and returns the result whenever that route is requested by the client.  In node.js, Express, the route handler might look like this: `app.get('/repository/load', function(req, res) { code here });`

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand the idea. I'm going to try node.js.

Comment: @RoodVleven - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.